# C# FullDescription of AutomationElement

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am using c# System.Windows.Automation to access Windows UI Automation but can not find option FullDescription. Some window controls have property FullDescription but I do not understand how can access this property by using System.Windows.Automation.

[image]

Comment: The Property Id is `30159`, so you can try with `var fullDescr = [AutomationElement].GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationProperty.LookupById(30159));`

Comment: Thenks @Jimi. You pointed out which direction to look in. AutomationProperty.LookupById(30159) returns null because System.Windows.Automation does not support a typed property for UIA_FullDescriptionPropertyId = 30159, but the following instruction works  [AutomationElement].NativeElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(30159)